# Random code not reading? cannot concatenate?

Tags: python, random, concatenation, easygui

```
PlayerAnswer = easygui.enterbox ("What is" +Figure1+ "+" +Figure2+ "?")
```

This line of code is not reading, both Figure1 and Figure2 are defined as random variables, and the `random` module is imported.

Here is how I've defined them at the top of the code:

```
Figure1 = random.randrange(0,11)
Figure2 = random.randrange(0,11)
```

The error I get is:

```
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects**
```

Here is the coding in context:

```
for number in range(0,11):
    PlayerAnswer = easygui.enterbox ("What is" +Figure1+ "+" +Figure2+ "?")
    if PlayerAnswer ==(Figure1 + Figure2):
            AdditionAnswers += 1
            easygui.msgbox ("Correct! Your score is "+str(AdditionAnswers))**
```

Comment: What does it mean for code to `read`?

Comment: You can't concatenate strings and integers.

Answer (score 1):

You can't add values with types that are of a string and an integer together. In order to make this work properly, you need to convert the two values to strings using the `str` function, like this:

```
PlayerAnswer = easygui.enterbox ("What is" + str(Figure1) + "+" + str(Figure2) + "?")
```

Comment: Thankyou so much! Seems so obvious now haha, thanks for your help :3